# "Error parsing inputs" when solving SDP using cvxpy on Google Collab

Tags: python, cvxpy

You can try to run this simple example of SDP using cvxpy on Google Collab and you will see that it doesn't work :
https://www.cvxpy.org/examples/basic/sdp.html
I really dont know why because it works on other environments.
I need to use Google Collab because py PC is very slow and Google collab makes things easier.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Doing ``!pip install --upgrade cvxpy`` to upgrade to the latest cvxpy 1.2.1 seems to solve the problem. The issue appeared in the scs interface, apparently. Maybe something about the default installation was broken.

Answer (score 0):

Code is perfectly working on my machine

According to the official page of CVXPY

These dependencies are needed

```
python >= 3.6
numpy >= 1.15
```

my configuration on colab

```
python: 3.7.14
numpy:  1.21.6
cvxpy:  1.2.1
```

So possible solution you can apply:

upgrade the library version that you use for your solution.